# macro to feed a calculated binding list into a 'let'?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'm trying different binding models for macro lambda lists.

Edit: in fact the lambda list for my test macros is always `(&rest ...)`. Which means that I'm 'destructuring' the argument list and not the lambda list. I try to get a solution that works for combining optional with key arguments or rest/body with key arguments - both combinations don't work in the Common Lisp standard implementation.

So I have different functions giving me a list of bindings having the same syntax as used by 'let'.

E.g:

```
(build-bindings ...) => ((first 1) middle (last "three"))
```

Now I thought to use a simple macro inside my test macros feeding such a list to 'let'.

This is trivial if I have a literal list:

```
(defmacro let-list (_list &rest _body)
  `(let ,_list ,@_body))

(let-list ((a 236)) a) => 236
```

But that's the same as a plain 'let'.

What I'd like to have is the same thing with a generated list.

So e.g.

```
(let-list (build-bindings ...)
    (format t "first: ~s~%" first)
    last)
```

with `(build-bindings ...)`, evaluated in the same lexical scope as the call `(let-list ...)`, returning

```
((first 1) middle (last "three"))
```

the expansion of the macro should be

```
(let
  ((first 1) middle (last "three"))

  (format t "first: ~s~%" first)
  last)
```

and should print `1` and return `"three"`.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Edit (to make the question more general):

If I have a list of `(symbol value)` pairs, i.e. same syntax that `let` requires for it's list of bindings, e.g. `((one 1) (two 'two) (three "three"))`, is there any way to write a macro that creates lexical bindings of the symbols with the supplied values for it's `&rest`/`&body` parameter?

This is seems to be a possible solution which Joshua pointed me to:

```
(let ((list_ '((x 23) (y 6) z)))

  (let
    ((symbols_(loop for item_ in list_
                    collect (if (listp item_) (car item_)  item_)))
     (values_ (loop for item_ in list_
                    collect (if (listp item_) (cadr item_)  nil))))

    (progv symbols_ values_
      (format t "x ~s, y ~s, z ~s~%" x y z))))

evaluates to:

;Compiler warnings :
;   In an anonymous lambda form: Undeclared free variable X
;   In an anonymous lambda form: Undeclared free variable Y
;   In an anonymous lambda form: Undeclared free variable Z
x 23, y 6, z NIL
```

I could also easily rearrange my `build-bindings` functions to return the two lists needed.

One problem is, that the compiler spits warnings if the variables have never been declared special.

And the other problem that, if the dynamically bound variables are also used in a surrounding lexical binding, they a shadowed by the lexical binding - again if they have never been declared special:

```
(let ((x 47) (y 11) (z 0))

  (let ((list_ '((x 23) (y 6) z)))

    (let
      ((symbols_(loop for item_ in list_
                      collect (if (listp item_) (car item_)  item_)))
       (values_ (loop for item_ in list_
                      collect (if (listp item_) (cadr item_)  nil))))

      (progv symbols_ values_
        (format t "x ~s, y ~s, z ~s~%" x y z)))))

evaluates to:

x 47, y 11, z 0
```

A better way could be:

```
(let ((x 47) (y 11) (z 0))

  (locally
    (declare (special x y))

    (let ((list_ '((x 23) (y 6) z)))

      (let
        ((symbols_(loop for item_ in list_
                        collect (if (listp item_) (car item_)  item_)))
         (values_ (loop for item_ in list_
                        collect (if (listp item_) (cadr item_)  nil))))

        (progv symbols_ values_
          (format t "x ~s, y ~s, z ~s~%" x y z))))))

evaluates to:

;Compiler warnings about unused lexical variables skipped
x 23, y 6, z NIL
```

I can't see at the moment whether there are other problems with the dynamic `progv` bindings.

But the whole enchilada of a `progv` wrapped in `locally` with all the symbols declared as special cries for a macro again - which is again not possible due to same reasons `let-list` doesn't work :(

The possiblilty would be a kind of macro-lambda-list destructuring-hook which I'm not aware of.

I have to look into the implementation of `destructuring-bind` since that macro does kind of what I'd like to do. Perhaps that will enlight me ;)

Comment: You know that you can't trivially generate the binding list at runtime? Imagine a compiler seeing the code and not executing it. It would need to run `build-bindings` at compile-time...

Comment: `build-bindings` is in fact executed at compile time and since it's for use inside macros and not inside functions, all the information necessary to 'destructure' the arguments in a custom way is present at compile time - assuming that I'm not wrong with this assumption.

The problem is how to insert the result of `build-binding` into a runtime `let`.

Comment: How can one run `build-bindings` at compile-time in a lexical environment, which does not exist then?

Comment: It's the lexical environment of the macro body at compile time - and that's exactly what I need for these custom bindings. E.g. if the lambda list is `(&rest _rest)` then the arguments to the macro are bound as a list in `_rest` which I destructure in turn.

Comment: Please show a concrete example of the code that you want to be able to write, and the code that it should expand to.  Having the shorthand `(let-list (bindings... ) ...)` doesn't tell us what you'd actually expect to have in place of `(bindings... )`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Did you read the last three code blocks in the question? There I described exactly what you asked for. I showed an example of what `(build-bindings ...)` could return and to what `(let-list (build-bindings ...) ...)` should expand. No problem to supply more examples, but sorry, I don't understand what you would like to see beyond what I provided.

Comment: @the upvoters of Joshua Taylor's comment: did you read the question? If yes then tell me what you would expect since everything Joshua Taylor requested is already in the post.

Comment: I have read the question and it is still not clear what you want. Should we read `(build-bindings ...)` as a function that returns `((first 1) middle (last "three"))`? If so, I don't think what you want is possible, in the way you want it.

Comment: I'm astonished ... before the first code block I wrote: "So I have different functions giving me a list of bindings having the same syntax as used by 'let'." followed by `(build-bindings ...) => ((first 1) middle (last "three"))` as a sample output of such a function. So why is it unclear that `build-bindings` is a function? Then I repeated that once more after the third code block: "with `(build-bindings ...)`, evaluated in the same lexical scope as the call `(let-list ...)`, returning" followed by a sample return of `((first 1) middle (last "three"))`.

Comment: @carpetemporem Yes, but what are the *arguments* to **build-bindings**? Is there something there that would allow us, at *compile time* to know that the variables will be `first`, `middle`, and `last` and that their values will be `1`, `nil`, and `"three"`? That's very important information for us, if we're going to help you solve this problem. The answer to "is there any way to write a macro that creates lexical bindings of the symbols with the supplied values for it's &rest/&body parameter?" is definitely **yes, but you need to be able to get those symbols at *macroexpansion* time**. Without

Comment: @carpetemporem knowing whether the code you want actually has those symbols at *macroexpansion* time, we can't know whether it's possible or not, and without seeing actual arguments in `(build-bindings ...)`, we don't know.  Now, if the `(build-bindings ...)` form is something that can be evaluated *at compile time*, then there may be a possibility here.

Comment: @carpetemporem At any rate, I've added an answer that includes what, I think, are the reasonable options you have, and shows the issues with the others.  If you can evaluate the **(build-bindings ...)** form at macroexpansion time, then you can include a call to **eval** in your macroexpansion.  If you can't, then you can't.  You haven't shown us what arguments you'd call **build-bindings** with, but only shown us **(build-bindings ...)** with an ellipsis, so we can't say whether it can be evaluated at macroexpansion time or not;  you'll have to answer that on your own.

Answer (score 7):

So a first (incorrect) attempt would look something like this:

```
(defun build-bindings ()
  '((first 1) middle (last "three")))

(defmacro let-list (bindings &body body)
  `(let ,bindings
     ,@body))
```

Then you could try doing something like:

```
(let-list (build-bindings)
  (print first))
```

That won't work, of course, because the macro expansion leaves the form **(build-bindings)** in the resulting **let**, in a position where it won't be evaluated:

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(let-list (build-bindings)
                                  (print first))))
(LET (BUILD-BINDINGS)
  (PRINT FIRST))
```

### Evaluation during Macroexpansion time

The issue is that you want the *result* of **build-bindings** at *macroexpansion* time, and that's *before* the code as a whole is run.  Now, in this example, **build-bindings** *can* be run at macroexpansion time, because it's not doing anything with any arguments (remember I asked in a comment what the arguments are?).  That means that you could actually **eval** it in the macroexpansion:

```
(defmacro let-list (bindings &body body)
  `(let ,(eval bindings)
     ,@body))
```

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(let-list (build-bindings)
                                  (print first))))
(LET ((FIRST 1) MIDDLE (LAST "three"))
  (PRINT FIRST))
```

Now that will work, insofar as it will bind **first**, **middle**, and **last** to **1**, **nil**, and **"three"**, respectively.  However, if **build-bindings** actually needed some arguments that weren't available at macroexpansion time, you'd be out of luck.  First, it *can* take arguments that are available at macroexpansion time (e.g., constants):

```
(defun build-bindings (a b &rest cs)
  `((first ',a) (middle ',b) (last ',cs)))
```

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(let-list (build-bindings 1 2 3 4 5)
                                  (print first))))
(LET ((FIRST '1) (MIDDLE '2) (LAST '(3 4 5)))
  (PRINT FIRST))
```

You could also have some of the variables appear in there:

```
(defun build-bindings (x ex y why)
  `((,x ,ex) (,y ,why)))
```

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(let-list (build-bindings 'a 'ay 'b 'bee)
                                  (print first))))
(LET ((A AY) (B BEE))
  (PRINT FIRST))
```

What you *can't* do, though, is have the variable names be determined from values that don't exist until runtime.  E.g., you can't do something like:

```
(let ((var1 'a)
      (var2 'b))
  (let-list (build-bindings var1 'ay var2 'bee)
    (print first))
```

because **(let-list (build-bindings …) …)** is macroexpanded *before* any of this code is actually *executed*.  That means that you'd be trying to evaluate **(build-bindings var1 'ay var2 'bee)** when **var1** and **var2** aren't bound to any values.

Common Lisp does *all* its macroexpansion first, and *then* evaluates code.  That means that values that aren't available until runtime are *not* available at macroexpansion time.

### Compilation (and Macroexpansion) at Runtime

Now, even though I said that Common Lisp does all its macroexpansion first, and then evaluates code, the code above actually uses **eval** at macroexpansion to get some extra evaluation earlier.  We can do things in the other direction too;  we can use **compile** at runtime.  That means that we can generate a lambda function and compile it based on code (e.g., variable names) provided at runtime.  We can actually do this *without* using a macro:

```
(defun %dynamic-lambda (bindings body)
  (flet ((to-list (x) (if (listp x) x (list x))))
    (let* ((bindings (mapcar #'to-list bindings))
           (vars (mapcar #'first bindings))
           (vals (mapcar #'second bindings)))
      (apply (compile nil `(lambda ,vars ,@body)) vals))))
```

```
CL-USER> (%dynamic-lambda '((first 1) middle (last "three")) 
                          '((list first middle last)))
;=> (1 NIL "three")
```

This compiles a lambda expression that is created at runtime from a body and a list of bindings.  It's not hard to write a macro that takes some fo the quoting hassle out of the picture:

```
(defmacro let-list (bindings &body body)
  `(%dynamic-lambda ,bindings ',body))
```

```
CL-USER> (let-list '((first 1) middle (last "three")) 
           (list first middle last))
;=> (1 NIL "three")
```

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(let-list (build-bindings)
                          (list first middle last)))
;=> (%DYNAMIC-LAMBDA (BUILD-BINDINGS) '((LIST FIRST MIDDLE LAST)))
```

```
CL-USER> (flet ((build-bindings ()
                  '((first 1) middle (last "three"))))
           (let-list (build-bindings)
             (list first middle last)))
;=> (1 NIL "three")
```

This gives you genuine lexical variables from a binding list created at runtime.  Of course, because the compilation is happening at runtime, you lose access to the lexical environment.  That means that the body that you're compiling into a function cannot access the "surrounding" lexical scope.  E.g.:

```
CL-USER> (let ((x 3))
           (let-list '((y 4))
             (list x y)))
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE X {1005B6C2B3}>.
```

### Using PROGV and special variables

If you don't need lexical variables, but can use special (i.e., dynamically scoped) variables instead, you can establish bindings at runtime using **progv**.  That would look something like:

```
(progv '(a b c) '(1 2 3)
  (list c b a))
;;=> (3 2 1)
```

You'll probably get some warnings with that if run it, because when the form is compiled, there's no way to know that a, b, and c are supposed to be special variables.  You can use **locally** to add some special declarations, though:

```
(progv '(a b c) '(1 2 3)
  (locally
      (declare (special a b c))
    (list c b a)))
;;=> (3 2 1)
```

Of course, if you're doing this, then you have to know the variables in advance which is *exactly* what you were trying to avoid in the first place.  However, if you're willing to know the names of the variables in advance (and [your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591537/macro-to-feed-a-calculated-binding-list-into-a-let/29609225?noredirect=1#comment47437178_29609225) seem like you might be okay with that), then you can actually use lexical variables.

### Lexical variables with *values* computed at run time

If you're willing to state what the variables will be, but still want to compute their values dynamically at run time, you can do that relatively easily.  First, lets write the direct version (with no macro):

```
;; Declare three lexical variables, a, b, and c.
(let (a b c)
  ;; Iterate through a list of bindings (as for LET)
  ;; and based on the name in the binding, assign the
  ;; corresponding value to the lexical variable that
  ;; is identified by the same symbol in the source:
  (dolist (binding '((c 3) (a 1) b))
    (destructuring-bind (var &optional value)
        (if (listp binding) binding (list binding))
      (ecase var
        (a (setf a value))
        (b (setf b value))
        (c (setf c value)))))
  ;; Do something with the lexical variables:
  (list a b c))
;;=> (1 NIL 3)
```

Now, it's not too hard to write a macrofied version of this.  This version isn't perfect, (e.g., there could be hygiene issues with names, and declarations in the body won't work (because the body is being spliced in after some stuff).  It's a start, though:

```
(defmacro computed-let (variables bindings &body body)
  (let ((assign (gensym (string '#:assign-))))
    `(let ,variables
       (flet ((,assign (binding)
                (destructuring-bind (variable &optional value)
                    (if (listp binding) binding (list binding))
                  (ecase variable
                    ,@(mapcar (lambda (variable)
                                `(,variable (setf ,variable value)))
                              variables)))))
         (map nil #',assign ,bindings))
       ,@body)))
```

```
(computed-let (a b c) '((a 1) b (c 3))
  (list a b c))
;;=> (1 NIL 3)
```

One way of making this cleaner would be to avoid the assignment altogether, and the computed values to provide the values for the binding directly:

```
(defmacro computed-let (variables bindings &body body)
  (let ((values (gensym (string '#:values-)))
        (variable (gensym (string '#:variable-))))
    `(apply #'(lambda ,variables ,@body)
            (let ((,values (mapcar #'to-list ,bindings)))
              (mapcar (lambda (,variable)
                        (second (find ,variable ,values :key 'first)))
                      ',variables)))))
```

This version creates a lambda function where the arguments are the specified variables and the body is the provided body (so the declarations in the body are in an appropriate place), and then applies it to a list of values extracted from the result of the computed bindings.

### Using LAMBDA or DESTRUCTURING-BIND

> *since I'm doing some "destructuring" of the arguments (in a bit a different way), I know which arguments must be present or have which
>   default values in case of missing optional and key arguments. So in
>   the first step I get a list of values and a flag whether an optional
>   or key argument was present or defaulted. In the second step I would
>   like to bind those values and/or present/default flag to local
>   variables to do some work with them*

This is actually starting to sound like you can do what you need to by using a lambda function or destructuring-bind with keyword arguments.  First, note that you can use any symbol as a keyword argument indicator.  E.g.:

```
(apply (lambda (&key
                    ((b bee) 'default-bee b?)
                    ((c see) 'default-see c?))
           (list bee b? see c?))
   '(b 42))
;;=> (42 T DEFAULT-SEE NIL)
```

```
(destructuring-bind (&key ((b bee) 'default-bee b?)
                          ((c see) 'default-see c?))
    '(b 42)
  (list bee b? see c?))
;;=> (42 T DEFAULT-SEE NIL)
```

So, if you just make your function return bindings as a list of keyword arguments, then in the destructuring or function application you can automatically bind corresponding variables, assign default values, and check whether non-default values were provided.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I read a lot of stuff, I tried a lot of stuff and I see now, that CL can't do what I want to do. To make it simple: I would like to evaluate certain parameters for macros instead of passing source code. And that would require some kind of runtime macro expansion model. Nonetheless I'm quite disappointed that "the extensible language" does only have a compile time macro expansion facility.

Comment: @carpetemporem Well, you *can* bind variables at runtime.  You'd use [**progv**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progv.htm) which takes a list of symbols and a list of values.  The issue with macroexpansion at runtime is that means you can't meaningfully *compile* code, since you never know what the code that would be compiled is going to be. (E.g., should the reference to **middle** be a lexical variable reference or a dynamic variable reference?  You can't know if you don't actually have the code.)

Comment: @carpetemporem You're right, though, that a language with a different design (e.g., that only permits interpreted code) could do this, even if Common Lisp can't.  You can certainly implement that language using Common Lisp.  It's also probably easier to write a workaround.

Comment: @carpetemporem Actually, I just thought of one more option that you might be interested in... let me write it up...

Comment: @carpetemporem Yes, please see the updated answer.  The first version of my answer described how you can do evaluation early (i.e., during the macroexpansion) phase, but completely neglected the fact that you can call the compiler (and, in turn, but not necessary here, the macroexpander) at runtime.  If you do that, then you *can* generate the lexical variables dynamically (but at the cost of losing some lexical access to surrounding code).  That may be a more helpful option.

Comment: Very clever Joshua! But as you wrote, you loose access to the lexical environment - so again not "the" solution. I tried also `progv`. Since it evaluates the arguments it seems like a good solution. At the moment I have no idea whether it's a disadvantage that the bound variables are dynamic ... The other thing is that the compiler spits warnings about undeclared free variables - I will edit the post to show them. Any idea how to disable them since declarations don't seem to be possible after `progv`?

Comment: Found `locally` to declare the variables as special. This solves the warnings and shadowing of the special variables by lexically enclosing bindings. Edited my post accordingly. Thanks for the `progv` hint. It may not be the end but at least a possible way.

Comment: @carpetemporem sure,  but now you're having to list the variables at compile time, which you were trying to avoid (wasn't that the whole point?0

Comment: @carpetemporem If you're willing to enumerate the variables at runtime, you can get all the lexical scoping you want;  it would just use a macro that would remember the names of the variables and then could set the values of the lexical variables when the "binding list" (which would now be more properly called a "value list")  arrives.  Would that be a more appealing solution?

Comment: @carpetemporem Since you seemed receptive to using locally and a special declaration with **progv**, which requires naming the variables in advance, I added that to the answer.  Since you seem willing to name the variables in advance, I added a (more preferable, in my opinion) way to exploit that and use lexical variables.

Comment: since I'm doing some "destructuring" of the arguments (in a bit a different way), I know which arguments must be present or have which default values in case of missing optional and key arguments. So in the first step I get a list of values and a flag whether an optional or key argument was present or defaulted. In the second step I would like to bind those values and/or present/default flag to local variables to do some work with them ...

Comment: @carpetemporem It actually sounds like [**destructuring-bind**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm) would be a pretty good fit then.  Any reason not to use it?  Note that you can use arbitrary symbols for keyword arguments, so you could turn a "binding list" `((a 1) b (c 3))` into a keyword argument list `(a 1 c 3)` and destructure it ala `(destructuring-bind (&key ((a a) 'default-a) ((b b) 'default-b) ((c c) 'default-c)) '(a 1 c 3) ...)`.

Comment: @carpetemporem I've updated my answer again;  it sounds like a function call or destructuring bind where the keyword arguments are the symbols that match up with your variables will actually handle this without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Acting a bit indirectly:

> a solution that works for combining optional with key arguments or
>   rest/body with key arguments

Have you considered the not-entirely-uncommon paradigm of using a sub-list for the keywords?

e.g.

```
 (defmacro something (&key (first 1) second) &body body) ... )
```

or, a practical use from Alexandria:

```
 (defmacro with-output-to-file ((stream-name file-name
                                 &rest args
                                 &key (direction nil direction-p)
                                 &allow-other-keys)
                                &body body)
```